# PDO QUOTE usases

Tags: php, pdo

```
if ( $db->exec(" UPDATE films SET 
                          title  = ". $db->quote($title) .",
                          duration = ". $db->quote($duration) .",
                          date = ". $db->quote($date) .",
                          about = ". $db->quote( $about).",
                          region = ". $db->quote($region) .",
                          f_state = ". $db->quote($state) ."
                           WHERE funique =  $lmk
                      ") ) {
                           }
```

Getting the PDOException error at title column. I did not find any wrong in statement.
Thank you.

Comment: since its PDO, why not use prepared statements instead

Comment: I am using main DB Object ,so I think I can use ->execute statements.

Comment: @Ghost Unfortunately, that is Syntax error  SQLSTATE[42000].

Answer (score 0):

Need to have single quotes around text for query to work (if twice single quote give issue try single of those or \' as I can not test right now ... we may need escape single quote to appear as text):

```
if ( $db->exec(" UPDATE 
                    films
                    SET 
                      title           =   ''". $db->quote($title) ."'',
                      duration        =   ". $db->quote($duration) .",
                      date    =   ''". $db->quote($date) ."'',
                      about           =   ''". $db->quote( $about)."'',
                      region          =   ''". $db->quote($region) ."'',
                      f_state           =   ''". $db->quote($state) ."''


                    WHERE funique =  $lmk

                  ") ) {


}
```

Comment: Thank you bur that did not help me.. we don't need to escaping for PDO quotes. I Think.